# Dynamically create multiline string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my first interaction ever with `JavaScript` so pls bear with me on this.

I want to dynamically create a multiline variable (string). The way it is going to be created based on some conditionals, something like

```
if (${{ inputs.a_gha_input }}) {
  add_this_line_to_a_multiline_js_var("Hello")
}
if (${{ inputs.another_gha_input }}) {
  add_this_line_to_a_multiline_js_var("World")
}
```

I would like my end result to be something like this

```
Hello
World
```

(in case both conditions are true of course)

Thanks

Comment: Where is this string going to be output? That will determine how the line breaks will be added. That being said, I would suggest you use an array for this. Put each line in its own entity of the array, then `join()` them together when required.

Comment: I don't get it if you are going to write to a file you need to append the "\n" character and if to the browser add a "<br />" tag?

Comment: This is my way of addressing [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/33413)

Comment: @Cyclonecode no need for tags

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, what do you mean "no need for tags"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use carriage return symbols in your multiline string. Your function `add_this_line_to_a_multiline_js_var(line)` may look something like this:

```
let multilineString = '';

function addLineToMultilineString(line) {
  multilineString += (line + '\n');
}
```